# How to display month in the format where month name would be words in power bi slicer?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to have a 'Between' date slicer with the month's name in words?

**For Example -
14 Jan 2021 to 14 Oct 2021.**

No matter what tantrum you do, the format remains all numerical in the slicer.